# deploy nodejs to http server on port 80

Tags: node.js, http, port80

I have small node js code to be deployed on the http server listening on port 80.
Below is the node.js server code listening on 8081.

```
var express = require('express'); // Web Framework
var app = express();
var sql = require('mssql'); // MS Sql Server client

// Connection string parameters.
var sqlConfig = {
    user: 'dbuser',
    password: 'dbpasswd',
    server: 'dbip',
    database : 'dbname',
    port:dbport
}




var server = app.listen(8081,'<serverip>', function () {
    var host = server.address().address
    var port = server.address().port

    console.log("app listening at http://%s:%s", host, port)
});

app.get('/table1', function (req, res) {

    sql.connect(sqlConfig, function(conerr,connection) {
      console.log(conerr);
       if (conerr) return;
         var request = new sql.Request();
        request.query('select * from table1', function(err, recordset) {
            if(err) console.log(err);
            console.log(recordset)
            res.end(JSON.stringify(recordset)); // Result in JSON format
        });
    });
})
```

The httpd conf file is as follows:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName <servername>
    <Directory "/var/www/html/njs/">
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
            ProxyPass /njs/  http://<serverip>:8081/
            ProxyPassReverse /njs/ http://<serverip>:8081/
</VirtualHost>
```

When I start my node server and hit the browser with url 'http://serverip/njs/table1' , I get "The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again." .

Any idea whats wrong. I am a newbie to nodejs .Please help

Comment: Does app.listen console statement show in your terminal

Comment: are you trying http://serverip:port/njs/table1 ?

Comment: yes I am able to get the reply mentioning the specific port. but the whole point is getting reply on port 80. As my requirement is to make it work on the existing webserver that listens on port 80

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is always better to use Nginx when deploying a Node server. A detailed tutorial of how to set it up is provided in the link below(If you are using Linux). It is very easy to setup and very powerful.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-node-js-application-for-production-on-ubuntu-16-04

Edited -

Here is an alternate solution to get node working in port 80.

https://gist.github.com/kentbrew/776580

You dont want any other server for that.

Comment: My requirement is to get this working on our existing http server. Getting to work it on nginx wont be useful in my case

Comment: Awseome, thanks Sunoj, updating iptables  works for me

Comment: Welcome. If found helpful, can you please upvote the answer.

Comment: Sure,,, thats done .. but looks like I dont have enough reputation, so doesnt showup publicly

Comment: That’s fine. Thanks.